# ASP.NET MVC 4: How to Obtain User Information from Twitter After Successful Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I may be pointed to some articles here, but I have read over two dozens and cant just figure out how to do this. I really need help.

I enabled Oauth on my MVC 4 application. Users can log in using Facebook and Twitter. I am able to fetch and use Facebook fields i.e.

```
dynamic response = client.Get("me", new { fields = "verified,name,gender,username,bio,cover,email,education,hometown,picture,website,work,location" });
```

However, I do not know how to return Twitter profile information of the just authenticated user. I see examples here about returning Tweets, but all I want is just to return the complete profile of the authenticated user. Has anyone succesfully done so in MVC4? Preferably in the

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {}
```

controller?

I read in many places that one needs to return Json object. I do not know Json which is why I am asking.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what your needs are or what you need to achieve with the user information that you return but there is an awesome Facebook Template written by the ASP.Net team which shows you how you can explore the users Graph on Facebook. You can find full information on the following link

[ASP.NET MVC Facebook Sample](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app)

I hope it helps.